# Can I use WCF Starter Kit HttpClient with confidence?

Tags: wcf, httpclient, rest

I would like to start using the WCF Rest Starter Kit's HttpClient to build clients for my Restful WCF services and I was wondering...

1. If anyone is currently experience
   any problems with it
2. Can I be  confident that future versions of
   the component (just the HttpClient,
   not worried about the rest of the
   kit) will not contain significant changes to the API?

It seems like a pretty straight-forward component so I can't imagine any major changes with it, but maybe somebody here who is more "in the know" could give me a heads up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until it's released, Microsoft will surely reserve the right to change it.

On the other hand, if you make sure they know you're using it, you're somewhat less likely to be, ummmm, *inconvenienced* by any changes.

Answer (score 8):

I work on the WCF team and I wrote most of the HttpClient code.

1. No major known issues. The public issue tracker is at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/List.aspx (search for HttpClient or WCF REST).
2. Microsoft does reserve the right to change it. That being said, I don't think there will be significant changes to the API that has shipped. (Maybe some minor renaming.) We're mostly considering adding features/capabilities, which shouldn't break your existing code.

A great way to tell us about your usage is via the forum: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9632199 .

Comment: Thanks John! We're going to be using it to consume our some of our WCF Rest at my company so I really appreciate the feedback.

Comment: JLamb, great to see you on stackoverflow.